# How can I get child object value from object in MUI Datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using this method:

```
useEffect(() => {
    PetService.getAll("/pets")
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.content);
      })
  }, [setData]);
```

and get this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1678181099411,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
        "content": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Tom",
                "type": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Cat"
                },
...
```

However, although I can get the content values properly, I cannot get `name` of the `type` value on MUI Datagrid. I use this config for columns:

```
export const petColumns = [
  { 
    field: "id", 

  },
  {
    field: "name",
    headerName: "Pet Name"

  {
    field: "type.name",
    headerName: "Type"
  }
];
```

So, how can I access the value of the child object? I also tried `"type['name']"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access nested objects with the `field` property, but can use a [value getter](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#value-getter):

```
export const petColumns = [
  { 
    field: "id", 

  },
  {
    field: "name",
    headerName: "Pet Name"

  {
    field: "type.name",
    headerName: "Type",
    valueGetter: ({ row }) => row.type.name
  }
];
```

Comment: Do you have an idea for populating data? Would you suggest a better solution than ``useEffect(() => {
    PetService.getAll("/pets")
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.content);
      })
  }, [setData]);`

Comment: @fredrick Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments and don't ask for opinions/suggestions. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for one specific, technical question per question.